# How to export canvas chart to excel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How to export to canvas chart to excel?
Here's my .cshtml code:

```
<div class="hrportalbody">
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <h3><b>DASHBOARD</b></h3>
  <hr />
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.Label("Year :", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Years", new List
        <SelectListItem>
          { new SelectListItem { Text="2017", Value="2017"}, new SelectListItem { Text="2018", Value="2018"}, new SelectListItem { Text="2019", Value="2019"}, new SelectListItem { Text="2020", Value="2020"}, new SelectListItem { Text="2021", Value="2021"}, new
          SelectListItem { Text="2022", Value="2022"}, new SelectListItem { Text="2023", Value="2023"} }, "Year", new { @class = "input-sm" })
          <input type="submit" value="FILTER" class="btn btn-info col-md-offset-1" />

          <span style="float:right;">
          <button id="downloadExcel">Download Chart Data As Excel</button>
          <br />
          <br />
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> }
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript code :

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

  window.onload = function() {

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      animationEnabled: true,
      title: {
        text: "Garansi Letter Based on Cost per-Month"
      },
      axisY: {
        title: "Company Cost",
        titleFontColor: "#4F81BC",
        lineColor: "#4F81BC",
        labelFontColor: "#4F81BC",
        tickColor: "#4F81BC"
      },
      axisY2: {
        title: "BPJS Cost",
        titleFontColor: "#C0504E",
        lineColor: "#C0504E",
        labelFontColor: "#C0504E",
        tickColor: "#C0504E"
      },
      toolTip: {
        shared: true
      },
      legend: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        itemclick: toggleDataSeries
      },
      data: [{
          indexLabelFontSize: 8,
          indexLabelFontFamily: "Lucida Console",
          indexLabel: "{z}",
          indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
          indexLabelOrientation: "horizontal",
          type: "column",
          name: "Company Cost",
          legendText: "Total Company Cost",
          showInLegend: true,
          dataPoints: [{
              label: "Januari",
              y: @ViewBag.jans,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.jans)
            },
            {
              label: "Februari",
              y: @ViewBag.febs,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.febs)
            },
            {
              label: "Maret",
              y: @ViewBag.mars,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.mars)
            },
            {
              label: "April",
              y: @ViewBag.aprs,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.aprs)
            },
            {
              label: "Mei",
              y: @ViewBag.meis,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.meis)
            },
            {
              label: "Juni",
              y: @ViewBag.juns,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.juns)
            },
            {
              label: "Juli",
              y: @ViewBag.juls,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.juls)
            },
            {
              label: "Agustus",
              y: @ViewBag.augs,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.augs)
            },
            {
              label: "September",
              y: @ViewBag.seps,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.seps)
            },
            {
              label: "Oktober",
              y: @ViewBag.okts,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.okts)
            },
            {
              label: "November",
              y: @ViewBag.novs,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.novs)
            },
            {
              label: "Desember",
              y: @ViewBag.dess,
              z: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.dess)
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          indexLabelFontSize: 8,
          indexLabelFontFamily: "Lucida Console",
          indexLabel: "{t}",
          indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
          indexLabelOrientation: "horizontal",
          type: "column",
          name: "BPJS Cost",
          legendText: "Total BPJS Cost",
          axisYType: "secondary",
          showInLegend: true,
          dataPoints: [{
              label: "Januari",
              y: @ViewBag.janb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.janb)
            },
            {
              label: "Februari",
              y: @ViewBag.febb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.febb)
            },
            {
              label: "Maret",
              y: @ViewBag.marb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.marb)
            },
            {
              label: "April",
              y: @ViewBag.aprb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.aprb)
            },
            {
              label: "Mei",
              y: @ViewBag.meib,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.meib)
            },
            {
              label: "Juni",
              y: @ViewBag.junb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.junb)
            },
            {
              label: "Juli",
              y: @ViewBag.julb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.julb)
            },
            {
              label: "Agustus",
              y: @ViewBag.augb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.augb)
            },
            {
              label: "September",
              y: @ViewBag.sepb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.sepb)
            },
            {
              label: "Oktober",
              y: @ViewBag.oktb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.oktb)
            },
            {
              label: "November",
              y: @ViewBag.novb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.novb)
            },
            {
              label: "Desember",
              y: @ViewBag.desb,
              t: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.desb)
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
    chart.render();

    function toggleDataSeries(e) {
      if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
      } else {
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
      }
      chart.render();
    }

    document.getElementById("downloadExcel").addEventListener("click", function() {
      downloadAsExcel({
        filename: "chart-data",
        chart: chart
      })
    });

    function downloadAsExcel(args) {
      var dataPoints, filename;
      filename = args.filename || 'chart-data';
      dataPoints = args.chart.data[0].dataPoints;
      dataPoints.unshift({
        y: "X Value",
        z: "Y-Value"
      });
      var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(dataPoints, {
        skipHeader: true,
        dateNF: 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'
      });
      if (!ws['!cols']) ws['!cols'] = [];
      ws['!cols'][0] = {
        wch: 17
      };
      var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, filename);
      XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename + ".xlsx");
    }
  }

  </script>
```

Can I do so using this Chart.js?

If yes, please suggest the probable solution or if no, please tell me if there's any open source tool to do so.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: According to [this question](https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/export-graph-and-its-data-into-excel/) there's no built-in feature to export chart data from Chart.js into Excel format. You can use library like EPPlus to generate Excel file from data source, but asking for proper tool to do something is off-topic here.

Comment: Removed duplicate paragraphs.